# node construct object with reading json files (and folders) recursively

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, read-write, json-server

I was not been able to find a solution to this specific problem, hence the query...

Basically, given the following directory structure...

```
rootfolder 
--- foldera
    --- foldera1
        ---scenario1.json
--- folderb
    --- folderb1
        ---scenario2.json
```

I want to create following json object using node.js

```
{
  "rootfolder": {
    "foldera": {
      "foldera1": {
        "scenario1": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "foobar"
        }
      }
    },
    "folderb": {
      "folderb1": {
        "scenario2": {
          "id": 202,
          "address": "somestreet",
          "postcode": 12334343
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so it uses folder and file names as json node and whenever it finds the json file it parses its content into object.

Any idea?

Comment: recursive fs.readdir into promise.reduce?

Comment: did you checked `glob` npm package?

Comment: What is your approach on this?

Comment: I have tried using various things such as glob, readdir but could not get it to work. I would really appriciate if someone can put some psudo code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you want to capture every route and write it on a json, so you have to read the entire path of your project. you can use regular expressions to save folder an file names on string, and then call the variable names in its order, i don't show you any code but i'm pretty sure the rest are gonna complete or suggest a better answer, good luck

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/fs.html